# How to start/stop motion on screen lock/unlock?

Tags: linux, script, gnome, motion-detection, motion

I installed `motion` in Fedora 17, and I want it to start when I lock the screen with `control + alt + l`, and stop when I unlock it.

I found this to run/stop a script on screen lock: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28181/run-script-on-screen-lock-unlock/28183#28183

The problem is that motion requires that I use `sudo`, eg: `$ sudo service motion start`

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 2):

You can run it with the option -n. `motion -n` runs it in non-deamon-mode, so u don't need to start  a service.

If its still not working try adding your user to the video group. Maybe you dont have permission to use the videodevice.

Hope I could help you.